# Error when compiling gst-rtsp-server example

Tags: gcc, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm currently trying to setup a Ubuntu server to redistribute a rtsp feed coming from an ip camera.

I saw that the [gst-rtsp-server library](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server) of gstreamer could help me with this issue.

I installed the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-rtsp
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

I then cloned the gst-rtsp-server library repo on my desktop:

```
git clone https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server.git
```

But, when I try to compile a C file (`gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch.c`) given as an example of how to use the library using gcc:

```
gcc test-launch.c -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccM7e45N.o: In function `main':
test-launch.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `g_option_context_new'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `g_option_context_add_main_entries'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `gst_init_get_option_group'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `g_option_context_add_group'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `g_option_context_parse'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `g_printerr'
test-launch.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `g_option_context_free'
test-launch.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `g_clear_error'
test-launch.c:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `g_option_context_free'
test-launch.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_new'
test-launch.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_new'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `g_object_set'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_new'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_server_attach'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `g_print'
test-launch.c:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_run'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There's something I'm missing but I don't know what... ><'

The error is obviously coming from a missing header, but which one and where can I get it?

As always, thanks for the help/tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this returns something for you:

```
pkg-config --modversion gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0
```

(For me, it returns `1.14.1`)

You can use the following gcc command to compile the wanted example:

```
gcc -o test-launch  test-launch.c  `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0`
```

P.S. in the command, make sure you use backticks ` and not apostrophes '

Source:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html#hello-world